# Timing Total crashes kernel

Tags: list-manipulation, crash

Here is a simple test function

```
test[n_] :=
  Module[{i = 0}, Total[Nest[{++i, #}&, {0}, n], -1]]
```

On my system V9.0.1 running OS X 10.6.8 and with a clean kernel, the following works

```
Timing[test[26198]]
```

> ```
> {0.106564, 343180701}
> ```

but then immediately evaluating

```
Timing[test[26199]]
```

fails. I get a beep and Help > Why the Beep?... shows

[image: alert.png]

Can anybody verify this on another system different from mine? Can you cast any light on why it happens? I will submit a bug report to WRI if this is not just peculiar to my system.

Comment: Both work fine here: mac os 10.9, Mathematica 9.01.

Comment: @bills. Could you try a really large number, say 10^6?

Comment: I confirm this behavior in *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64: `Timing[test[261990]]` crashes the kernel.

Comment: Crashes 8.0.4 Linux 64bit

Comment: Crashes without `Timing` too, but the number at which it crashes varies a bit. `test[21820]` crashes sometimes, but if it doesn't crash on first-run it can be evaluated seemingly endless amount of times without crashing.

Comment: I tested for all the numbers mentioned, it works. In my system, Windows 8 (64 bits), it seems to work up to 174657.

Comment: I tried `test[n_] := Module[{i = 0}, Total[y = Nest[{++i, #} &, {0}, n], -1]];test[174657];y` and it results in "$RecursionLimit::reclim".

Comment: You are blowing up the subroutine stack. Whether this is a consequence of evaluation semantics, or vagary of (mis?)implementation of `Nest`, I do not know.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. Thanks for your insight. Should I report this to WRI tech support?

Comment: You can submit it. But the fact is I do not know at this time whether it is a bug or a fact of evaluation semantics. If the latter, there won't be much to be done about it. Time permitting, I hope to look into that next week.

Comment: As ssch mentioned it doesn't seem to be related to the `Timing` at all, so you might want to change that in your question and title...

Comment: @AlbertRetey. No, because I love the alliteration.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Also with `Timing` we have rhyming.

Comment: I looked some more. The issue is that `Total` is implemented by recursion. This could be done differently (many things could be done differently...) and I imagine a suggestion will be, or has been, filed to this effect. Not sure if/when it might be acted upon. I'd suggest using `Flatten` first since that one is not done by recursion (not since version 3.0, at any rate).

Comment: @m_goldberg and daniel: OK, I understand that my priorities are not shared by the majority :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported my problem to Wolfram Research technical support. Here is a slightly edited version of the reply I received.

> ... I tried the same command with larger value[s] of n and the crash could be reproduced with Total applied. Indeed, this number seems to be system dependent. I tested it on several different machines and got different thresholds of n.
>
> ...
>
> Regarding this, I will file a report so the developer who is responsible for the function Total will notice the issue.

I think this issue can be marked with [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).