# ToExpression fails with long nested string expressions

Tags: import, string-manipulation, recursion, streams, system-limitations

Consider the following conversion from `String` to Mathematica Expression:

```
n = 10;
ToExpression[Table["{", {n}] <> Table["}", {n}]]
```

> ```
> {{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}
> ```

Everything is fine.

However, when the string is longer:

```
n = 510;
ToExpression[Table["{", {n}] <> Table["}", {n}]]
```

> ```
> ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before "                                                                               
>
>                          <<182>>                                                                                                
>                ^".
> $Failed
> ```

My actual string that I'm trying to convert is much longer, about 2 million characters. How can I convert it to a Mathematica expression? A short example is:

> "{"GAME", {"version", "0.23.5"}, {"linkURL", ""}, {"Mode", "1"}, {"PARAMETERS", {"FLIGHT", {"CanQuickSave", "True"}, {"CanQuickLoad", "True"}}}, {"SCENARIO", {"name", "ScenarioDiscoverableObjects"}, {"scene", "7, 8, 5"}, {"", "703987854"}, {"sizeCurve", {"key", "0 0 1.5 1.5"}, {"key", "0.3 0.45 0.875 0.875"}}}}"

**UPDATE**
`Read`ing a `Stream` also fails:

```
n = 510;
string = Table["{", {n}] <> Table["}", {n}];
stream = StringToStream[string]
Read[stream, Expression]
Close[stream]
```

> ```
> Read::readt: Invalid input found when reading {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{\[Ellipsis]
> }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
>  from StringToStream[{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{\[Ellipsis]
> }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}]. >>
> ```

Comment: fyi, tried it on V10 at WPC, and it failed there at 351 not 182. Not sure if this makes any difference. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EJBba.png)

Comment: Not true for _any_ string, though. `n = 510; ToExpression[Table["1+1+", {n}] <> Table["1+1", {n}]]`

Comment: @shrx How do you create your data? I suppose you do this in Mathematica as well? If you do create your data in Mathematica, I might have a workaround.

Comment: I can reproduce this with V.9.0.1 on OS X. It looks like a bug to me. The string of braces is built with no problem. It's `ToString` that's stumbling. I've found another place where _Mathematica_ has trouble with deeply nested lists. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37132/3066). I would say it's a bug.

Comment: @halirutan see my [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52079/creating-a-nested-menu-with-openerview). You can see the original structure of the file I'm trying to parse.

Comment: Why not use Nest[{#} &, {}, 5514 - 1]? this one can success.

Answer (score 10):

(All observations made in version 7.)

There seems to be a limitation for input even in the Front End (Notebook interface), in that if I enter more than **766** levels of nested lists I get a `MaxFormatDepthExceeded` expression and an error beep.  The help text is:

> A box structure with a depth exceeding the maximum allowed depth was encountered.

We can at least get this 766 level input by using the function `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket` shown by John Fultz [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/121), which I will bundle as:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]
```

We can then do:

```
n = 766;
string = Table["{", {n}] <> Table["}", {n}];
expr = ToExpression @@ parseString[string];
ToString[expr] === string
```

> ```
> True
> ```

To extend this further would apparently require avoiding an intermediate Box structure which is an interesting problem.  However it's the Fourth of July and I'll be spending my evening doing something else! :-)

---

**Update:** Using version 10, and increasing `$RecursionLimit` as Michael commented, we can use the method above for up to `n = 5514`:

```
$RecursionLimit = 1*^6;

n = 5514;

string = Table["{", {n}] <> Table["}", {n}];
expr = ToExpression @@ parseString[string];
ToString[expr] === string
```

> ```
> True
> ```

However a higher value crashes *Mathematica* without warning.  (Version 10.0.0.0 under Windows.)

Comment: FYI: This seems to work up to `n = 2941` if I  `Block` or set `$RecursionLimit = 2942` or more in V9.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

What you experience here seems to be some kind of stack limit when you have nested expressions. It doesn't seem to matter whether you nest lists or function calls. Look for instance at [this example](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Fz72pXYJ) here which is nothing more than a nested call `f[f[f[...f[a]]..]`

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

On the other hand, if the parser doesn't need to build up such a large stack, it seems to work. In an example of `a+a+...+a` which you can [find here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8B53cyZX) the `Get` works like a charm:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that it doesn't seem to make a difference whether you use `Get` or `Import` on a file, or `ToExpression` or `ImportString` on strings. The error stays the same here.

I'm not sure what I can propose you as workaround. Have you noticed that when you copy&paste the nested expressions directly, it works? It really seem to be a limitation of the reading from a stream.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my solution maybe pretty easy,but it can works:

```
 n = 5;
 ToExpression[Table["{", {n}] <> Table["}", {n}]] == Nest[{#} &, {}, n - 1]
```

> True

And if I set n a large number:

```
n=2*10^6; 
Nest[{#} &, {}, n];
Depth[%]
```

> 2000002

Also works.