# How to explode set of lists into subsets under criterion?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following example set

```
set = { {a,{1,2,3}} , {b,{1}} , {c,{2,3}} , {d,{4,5}} , {e,{5}} };
```

I would like to have a function (lets call it `magic[x_]`) that looks at the lists `set[[i,2]]` and groups the elements `i` of `set` into new sets such as to separate disjoint lists. For example:

```
magic[set]
```

> `{ { {a,{1,2,3}} , {b,{1}} , {c,{2,3}} } , { {d,{4,5}} , {e,{5}} } }`

which grouped elemets containing lists with overlapping entries `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5}` but each disjoint from one another. Is there a function in Mathematica which can be used to achieve that? Or maybe this can be implemented conveniently? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want exactly, but does this work? `Gather[set, IntersectingQ[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] &]`. It works for your example, but does it work for more general `set`s?

Comment: Wow, yes this works! I did not expect it to be this simple. Just out of curiosity, how do you think would one implement it if it had to be done in a more low level programming language?

Comment: That's a question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Feyre oh, ok, I understand.

Comment: @march `Gather` expects an equivalence relation as its second argument. `IntersectingQ` is not one. The results will be unpredictable. Example: `sets = Partition[Range[5], 2, 1]; Gather[sets, IntersectingQ]`

Comment: @Kagaratsch To implement connected components directly, using Mathematica, see the first link [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5173/12).

Comment: Related: [(92627)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92627/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Overlapping" is not an equivalence relationship because it is not transitive. So approaches using `Gather` and related functions are not possible.

The simplest, though not the most efficient way is to test every pair of elements from the set.  After doing that, we can treat this as a [`ConnectedComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedComponents.html) problem.

Code:

```
set = {{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {b, {1}}, {c, {2, 3}}, {d, {4, 5}}, {e, {5}}};

am = Outer[Boole@IntersectingQ[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] &, set, set, 1]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}} *)

components = ConnectedComponents@AdjacencyGraph[am]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}} *)

Part[set, #] & /@ components
(* {{{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {b, {1}}, {c, {2, 3}}}, {{d, {4, 5}}, {e, {5}}}} *)
```

---

**Addendum**

This is what could happen if we try to use `Gather` anyway:

```
sets = Partition[Range[5], 2, 1]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)

Gather[sets, IntersectingQ]
(* { {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, 
     {{3, 4}, {4, 5}} } *)
```

Comment: I suspected something of this sort. Is there an obvious example for which the simple `Gather[set, IntersectingQ[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] &]` doesn't work? (And as a side note, you imply that `Gather` assumes transitivity, which means that it *does not* test every pair? Rather, I imagine it basically makes the sublists on the fly, and for each new check, it just checks to see if *one* of the elements already in the sublist matches with the new element. Is this correct?)

Comment: @march I think that is correct, see edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's an important thing that definitely passed me by.

Answer (score 2):

```
ConnectedComponents @ SimpleGraph @ RelationGraph[IntersectingQ @@ {##}[[All, 2]]&, set]
```

> {{{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {b, {1}}, {c, {2, 3}}},
>    {{d, {4, 5}}, {e, {5}}}}